# VBScript to PHP

Tags: php

I want to make this following VBScript into PHP:

```
Dim RootDomain : RootDomain = Request.ServerVariables("server_name")
Dim paryDomain : paryDomain = Split(RootDomain,".")

IF uBound(paryDomain) = 1 THEN
  RootDomain = paryDomain(0) & "." & paryDomain(1)
ELSEIF uBound(paryDomain) = 2 THEN
  RootDomain = paryDomain(1) & "." & paryDomain(2)
END IF
IF RootDomain = "storeboard.com" THEN
  G_SYSTEMID = 1
ELSEIF RootDomain = "dcwn.org" THEN
  G_SYSTEMID = 2
END IF
```

I have made the following:

```
$Domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$paryDomain = explode(".",$Domain);
$Array = count($paryDomain)

if ($Array == "1")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[0].'.'.$paryDomain[1];
}    
elseif ($Array == "2")
{
    $RootDomain = $paryDomain[1].'.'.$paryDomain[2];
}

echo $RootDomain
```

I am a beginner with PHP, and I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\inetpub\mydomain.com\testing\test_sql_server.php on line 53
```

Line 53 is:

```
if ($Array == "1")
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy one: you just missed a semi-colon:

```
$Array = count($paryDomain)
```

should be

```
$Array = count($paryDomain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgot a `;`:

```
$Array = count($paryDomain);
                           ^---here
```

In general, if you get an "unexpected SOMETHING" error in php, always look at the line(s) **BEFORE** the indicated error line. that line's probably fine... the actual error occurred earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a semicolon on line 3 and on the last line.